# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DataSynthesizer'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the DataSynthesizer package. I installed it.
When using it in my code as follows:

`from DataDescriber import DataDescriber`

I get the error:

```
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\DataSynthesizer\DataDescriber.py in <module>
      5 from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
      6 
----> 7 from DataSynthesizer.datatypes.AbstractAttribute import AbstractAttribute
      8 from DataSynthesizer.datatypes.DateTimeAttribute import is_datetime, DateTimeAttribute
      9 from DataSynthesizer.datatypes.FloatAttribute import FloatAttribute

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DataSynthesizer'
```

The error is in DataDescriber.py, not in my code.
I tried to install the package in different ways, but the error still exists.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146. If the error happens ultimately in code you didn't write, then we need to see the chain of calls starting in your code in order to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the way you're trying to import it. You're trying to import DataDescriber from DataDescriber, instead of importing DataDescriber from the module itself. If you do "from DataSynthesizer import DataDescriber" it should work, as it did for me. If it still does not work, try using PipEnv to isolate it from other module interference.